# How to add a field to sale order lines?

Tags: xml, odoo-8

I would like to add the "ship" field to the sale order lines as a drop down list (many2one field).

My xml file  *ship_view.xml*:

```xml
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="ship_orderline">
    <field name="model">sale.order.line</field>
    <field name="name">sale.form</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">   
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/tree/field[@name='product_uom_qty']" position="before">
            <field name="ship"/>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this belowing code. Check out that the model should be `sale.order` in the view:

**Python code**

```python
from openerp import models, fields


class CustomSaleOrderLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'

    ship = fields.Char(
        string='Ship',
    )
```

**XML view**

```xml
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="ship_orderline">
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="name">sale.order.form</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">  
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/tree//field[@name='product_uom_qty']" position="before">
            <field name="ship"/>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: I am a newbie in odoo and sof . I tried your correction but i got the error TypeError: Type is not a constructor. Also i would like add this field to tree view.

Comment: I tested it and it works, where did you define the field `ship`?

Comment: I edited my answer with the field definition. I hope it will help you

Comment: the problem lies with the model(sales.order.line) , also **/tree/field** is enough  instead of **/tree//field**

Comment: This works fine **<xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/tree/field[@name='product_uom_qty']" position="after">**